# phpspreadsheet: Problem with IReadFilter and getVisible

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I try to read Values from a large excel-file (xlsx) via phpspreadsheet.

1. I only need the first lines, so I use a simples `IReadFilter`.
2. I only want to get the values of the columns, that are not hidden. I would expect that `getVisible()` would work. Unfortunately, `getVisible()` only seems to work if I read the spreadsheet via `$spreadsheet=IOFactory::load($inputFileName);`.
   If I read it via the `IReadFilter`, then all columns are always displayed.

Here is an example of code:

```php
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$inputFileName='./filename.xslx';

class MyReadFilter implements IReadFilter {
    public function readCell($columnAddress,$row,$worksheetName=''): bool {
        // read only the first 5 Lines
        if($worksheetName=='Komplett' && $row>5) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

// -----------------------------------

// 1) When I use this variant, the iReadFilter works to load only the first lines.
// But getVisible() shows every column
$filterSubset=new MyReadFilter();
$reader=IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$reader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
$spreadsheet=$reader->load($inputFileName);

// 2) With this variant getVisible() works
// $spreadsheet=IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$sheet=$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator=$row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

    foreach($cellIterator as $col_id=>$cell) {
        // Show only Columns that are not hideen
        if($sheet->getColumnDimension($col_id)->getVisible()) {
            print($col_id." ".$cell->getValue()."\n");
        } else {
            print("Break, Column ".$col_id." (".$cell->getValue().") is hidden!\n");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to use `getVisible()` in connection with an `iReadFilter`? Or have I done something wrong?
I would be happy to receive any hints!

Comment: Don't know if I just misreads here. But you are hiding all rows after the fifth row? All columns are visible still? Columns are at horizontal axis and rows is the vertical axis, so it is not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your asking!
The file is very large, so I want to skip most part of it for testing.
The important thing for me is to determine, which coloums are hidden. In the example code all coloums are shown.